# 20.04 ram issues

Tags: firefox, 20.04, ram, ide

recently after updating to ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu suddenly uses a lot of ram more ram than it used to. In daily usage, it has gone from using like 5GB of ram to like 11GB  I don't even run that much. All I basically run is Firefox with about 8 tabs in general and a bunch of addons. I also run some JetBrains IDE whether that is pycharm, phpstorm or even rider. It still manages to eat up ram to about 11GB. Does anyone know any tools I can use to see how I can decrease the ram usage? Even something that will try and decrease ram usage for me.

Edit 1:
Here is the output of `free -h`

[image: free-h]

Edit 2:
Here are the other 2 outputs
[image: sysctl vm.swappiness]

[image: top]

Edit 3:
here is `snap list` and `ls -al`

[image: snap list]

Edit 4:
here is gnome extensions ls -al
[image: local gnome extensions]
[image: global gnome extensions]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `top` (after you've seen the memory usage increase).

Comment: Also show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Status please...

Comment: You can see which program is eating up your memory via Gnome system monitor or [Htop](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/) Some Gnome extensions had some bugs in the past that caused high memory usage . It also might be the Xorg server that uses that much mem.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I do need to see the other command outputs that I requested. Also, make sure to notify me when you update your question, by sending me a comment that starts with @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I have updated my question to include this thanks.

Comment: **Ah! There's your problem... Discord!** More on that later. Show me `snap list` and also the remaining two `ls -al` commands that I requested.

Comment: @heynnema here you go

Comment: Thanks for the info. The `snap list` command came out fine, but you gave me a generic `ls -al` command. Please edit those out of your question, and show me the `ls -al` commands from my 2nd comment, above. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema alright

Comment: @heynnema here I have updated it with everything needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108751/discussion-between-rodude123-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 0):

Check and ajust **content process limit** in Firefox preferences.

[image]

In my case I unchecked "Use recommended performance settings" and reduced the limit from 8 (which was default and is still "recommended") to 1. Firefox stopped eating RAM. But twitch and youtube streaming in multiple tabs had noticeably degraded and almost became unusable. Later I increased the number to 4 and I didn't notice increase in RAM usage but browser was able to properly render heavy content again.
After the entire day in Pycharm and Firefox my RAM is only 46% full instead of 90+% that I experienced during previous couple of months.

For reference, specs of my laptop are intel i5-8265U (4 core, 8 threads) and 16 GB of RAM.

My case was really similar because I also use Pycharm (maximum heap size set to 4gb), latest Firefox with 8-10 addons and 10-100 tabs (when I closed all but 5-6 tabs, Firefox didn't free RAM) and a couple of more lightweight apps on my Ubuntu 20.04. So I hope my answer qualifies as proper answer.

The downside is I was not able to use any tools to inspect and resolve the problem. Almost pure random.
Buttons in `about:memory` didn't reduce the RAM usage from ~10GB level even if I left only one tab with some lightweight html page (Hacker News, for example).
`about:performance` was useless as well, it didn't show high RAM usage.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems as of Firefox 99 the "Content process limit" option is no longer exposed in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
about:config
```

search for

[image: LowMemory]

set it to true. Restart firefox.

Comment: As of Firefox 99, was true for me by default.